# Is my understanding of least upper bound property correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Am I correct to understand that if a set $S$ has least upper bound property, then its any upper-bounded subset $A$ will have $\sup(A)$ containing in $S$?

Does it basically just mean that some sets contain all the least upper bounds of their baby subsets in them? and some don't, like $\mathbb Q$?

like it just tells us what we can find in a bigger set (if we move from a smaller set)? its fillings?

Comment: Yes and no.  If $~A \subseteq S~$ then $\text{sup}(A) \leq \text{sup}(S).~$  However, $~\text{sup}(S)~$ might not be an element of $~S,~$ and you could have $~\text{sup}(A) = \text{sup}(S).$

Comment: It's not clear whether by $S$ you mean a partial ordering with the least upper bound property, or just a set contained in such a partial ordering.